# How to install php-memcached extension on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: php, apache, memcached, macos-sierra

I installed successfully memcached-server, but got an error in my php-script:

> Class 'Memcached' not found

I should to install php-memcached extension to fix it, but i dont know how.

I searched howto's, but all what i found is about installing php5*-memcached with brew. But i need an extension for php7.1,

brew install php71-memcached doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
pecl install memcached
```

[Memcached extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) is available for PHP 7.0.0 or newer.

Comment: I'm using Valet and want both 7.4 and 8.x available. When I run `pecl install memcached` I get a message that it's already installed. But when I run Valet I get the message that's compiled with the wrong version of PHP. How can I recompile the ext for PHP 8?